# 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0432' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract the caption corresponding to every video_id for the json file.
The file is present in test_videodatainfo.jason.zip-->[enter link description here](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/h14iarbs62e7p/shared)

```
import json
import csv
with open('D:/Final Year Project/test_videodatainfo/test_videodatainfo.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
capdata = data['sentences'] 
data_file = open('D:/Final Year Project/test_videodatainfo/data_file.csv', 'w') 

csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file) 

count = 0

for cap in capdata: 
    if count == 0: 
        header = cap.keys() 
        print(cap.keys())
        csv_writer.writerow(header) 
        count += 1
    csv_writer.writerow(cap.values()) 
data_file.close()
```

the output is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgsna.png)

Comment: It would be beneficial to provide the whole console output in the body of your question rather than just the error code in your title please.

Comment: added the pic of the output @Lamma

Comment: In the future you can just paste it in the question body also.